# Dynamic sql and spexecutesql behavior

Tags: sql-server, string, sp-executesql

I have a table like

```
c1  c2    c3  c4
-----------------
2    1    7    13 
9    2    8    14
1    3    9    15
5    4   10    16
2    5   11    17
11   6   12    18
```

As in general I would not know the number of columns (in the code @d here 4) to get a string in the form:

```
2,9,1,5,2,11,  1,2,3,4,5,6,  7,8,9,10,11,12,  13,14,15,16,17,18
```

To do so I am doing:

```
 DECLARE  @d INT
         ,@counterI INT
         ,@template AS nvarchar(max) 

   SET  @d  = 4;       
   SET  @counterI   = 1;
   Set  @template = 'SELECT STUFF( 
                         (  SELECT  '','' + CAST([col] AS VARCHAR) FROM (';                        
   WHILE (@counterI < @d) BEGIN
        SET @template += ' SELECT [c'+CAST(@counterI-1 AS VARCHAR)+'] AS col FROM [MyTable] UNION ALL ';
        SET @counterI   = @counterI + 1; 
   END
  Set  @template += ' SELECT [c'+CAST(@counterI-1 AS VARCHAR)+'] AS col FROM [MyTable] ' 
  Set  @template += ') alldata FOR XML PATH('''')  )  ,   1  ,   1  ,  '''' )';    

declare @CommaString varchar(max)
set @CommaString = ''
exec sp_executesql @template, N'@CommaString varchar(max) out', @CommaString out
```

So if I do

```
select @CommaString;
```

[image]

Why is not `@CommaString` at the moment of selecting it returning the string if when doing the sp_executesql it is printing it right?

Comment: Have you checked @template has what you expect in it?  Your example table had columns numbered 1-4, and your SQL looks like it would work on columns numbered 0-3?  Also, you have two different table names in your SQL?

Comment: sorry, I did not copied the code right, I have updated it, and also, yes, the var @template has what I expect, in fact I execute that query and gives me the string, the problem yields in spexecsql part....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be missing something about how sp_executesql works, but don't you need something like 'SELECT @CommaString = ...' in @template, so that it assigns the comma string to the out parameter?

Just to clarify, I think you need something like:

```
DECLARE  @d INT
        ,@counterI INT
        ,@template AS nvarchar(max) 

SET  @d  = 4;       
SET  @counterI   = 1;
Set  @template = 'SELECT @CommaString = STUFF( 
                     (  SELECT  '','' + CAST([col] AS VARCHAR) FROM (';                        
WHILE (@counterI < @d) BEGIN
    SET @template += ' SELECT [c'+CAST(@counterI-1 AS VARCHAR)+'] AS col FROM [MyTable] UNION ALL ';
    SET @counterI   = @counterI + 1; 
END
Set  @template += ' SELECT [c'+CAST(@counterI-1 AS VARCHAR)+'] AS col FROM [MyTable] ' 
Set  @template += ') alldata FOR XML PATH('''')  )  ,   1  ,   1  ,  '''' )';    

declare @CommaString varchar(max)
set @CommaString = ''
exec sp_executesql @template, N'@CommaString varchar(max) out', @CommaString = @CommaString out
```

As a simpler example, something like this is perhaps easier to read/see what I mean:

```
declare @CommaString varchar(max)
set @CommaString = ''
exec sp_executesql 'SELECT @CommaString = ''1,2,3''', '@CommaString varchar(max) out', @CommaString = @CommaString out
```

Incidentally, I've usually seen this kind of thing for string concatenation:

```
DECLARE @MyString varchar(max)

SET @MyString = ''

SELECT @MyString = @MyString + ',' + MyColumn
  FROM MyTable
```

Comment: it is supposed that in the line `exec sp_executesql @template, N'@CommaString varchar(max) out', @CommaString out`  the part `@CommaString out` does what you say, but still can not find the error...

Comment: You've declared the out parameter in the exec statement, but the contents of @template doesn't seem to make any attempt to set it?

Comment: Well, that is the reason to be of first parameter in the instruction `exec sp_executesql @template, N'@CommaString varchar(max) out', @CommaString out` aka @template

Comment: @James is right.  In this example, you would need to use @CommaString **inside** @template: `Set  @template = 'SELECT @CommaString = STUFF( 
                         (  SELECT  '','' + CAST([col] AS VARCHAR) FROM (';`.  I'm not sure that's the only problem, but it's a start.

Comment: My understanding is that the first parameter is the SQL to execute, the second parameter is the parameter definitions, and the rest of the parameters are the actual arguments themselves, which it seems should be in the form of @a = @a, @b = @b out and so on, but even with all of that, I thought the contents of the first parameter, i.e. the actual SQL, should make reference to the parameters, e.g. @a and @b in the above to use them as inputs/outputs.